# PHP like array handling in Python: Indexing multidimensional array

Tags: php, python, arrays, multidimensional-array

This feels like a stupid question, but I cannot find an answer anywhere.
I am trying to learn python, so I figured I could try to create a little command line control for my lights and locks etc. (I have made my own home automation with Arduino).

To my question:
I want the Python equivalent to PHP's:

```
$array = array('light' => array('on', 'off'), 'lock' => array('lock', 'unlock'));
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can use a dictionary for this:

```
>>> dct = {'light': ['on', 'off'], 'lock': ['lock', 'unlock']}
>>> dct
{'lock': ['lock', 'unlock'], 'light': ['on', 'off']}
```

Another option is to use the `dict()` constructor, but this requires the keys to be valid Python [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers):

```
>>> dct = dict(light=['on', 'off'], lock=['lock', 'unlock'])
>>> dct
{'lock': ['lock', 'unlock'], 'light': ['on', 'off']}
```

Note that the above two methods won't preserve the order though, if order matters then you should use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dct = OrderedDict((('light', ['on', 'off']), ('lock',['lock', 'unlock'])))
>>> dct
OrderedDict([('light', ['on', 'off']), ('lock', ['lock', 'unlock'])])
```